# React props test case not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing test cases for react Error Boundary component which has the following props-

1. FallBack
2. OnError

In App.js, I wrap the Home container - Home.js and pass props like this-

```
<ErrorBoundary 
FallBack={<Fallback/>}>
<Home/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Note- Fallback is another component that I've imported and passed as props to error boundary component.
Now the returned render value is different based on whether prop is passed or not.

While writing test case in App.js, I get the desired output if prop is present. If not, how can I write that? Tried creating Home.test.js and wrapping it around ErrorBoundary, but didn't give expected output.

```
test('To render common message if prop passed',()=>{
const wrapper = render(
<ErrorBoundary FallBack={<Fallback/>}>
    <Home/>
    </ErrorBoundary>
)
expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Note- Snapshot returns Home page with a title 'Welcome to React', which is not expected, but 'Something went wrong', which is a component that ErrorBoundary component displays and imports in it's file.